# Delegating Kubernetes Operator: parent - child Custom Resource relationship

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

Let's say I have 2 operators, a Manager and Component operator. The Manager receives a Custom Resource with multiple nested resources:

```
kind: ManagerResource
spec:
    componentKind: ComponentA
    .... spec for componentA
```

and it's job is to delegate the handling of ComponentA to the Component operator. It also needs to watch for changes to ComponentA.

Is it possible to have the Manager operator invoke the Component operator on ComponentA, and then have them both watch the created resource? Any examples or details on how the protocol might work?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.